# finalize method getting illegalstateexception not inside a request scope

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, hk2

I have a model inside a singleton Binder service and it is injected as request scope object. Service can use that model without any exception.

But when garbage collector try to finalize that model, it gets illegalStateException: not inside request scope.

Is there any idea?

```
public class App extends ResourceConfig {
    public App() {
        register(new Binder());
    }
}

public class Binder extends AbstractBinder{
    
     @Override
     protected void configure() {
         bindFactory(ModelFactory.class)
        .proxy(true)
        .proxyForSameScope(false)
        .to(Model.class)
        .in(RequestScoped.class);
     }
}

@Provider
public class ModelFactory implements Factory<Model> {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;
    
    @Override
    public Model provide() {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setHeaderParam(request.getHeader("key"));
        return model;
    }
}

public Service {

     @Context
     Model model;
}
```

Comment: This may be a bug in that the finalizer is running in the GC context, not the context of the RequestScope.  You should probably raise this as an issue at https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish-hk2/issues

Comment: I edited the question. HttpServletRequest is a proxy object. Is it possible that it causes the  exception?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. After HttpServletRequest ends garbage collector tries to finalize the Model. But at that point hk2-locator MethodInterceptor intercepts and try to find or create the object. Meanwhile there is no RequestScope, so "Not inside a request scope" exception is thrown.

The exception does not cause application error, but i do not want to see the error.

If anyone finds a solution please inform me.